# Creating and assigning console.log a new object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have seen code like this in several places:

```
(function() {
    var method;
    var noop = function noop() {};
    var methods = [
        'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
        'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
        'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
        'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
    ];
    var length = methods.length;
    var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

    while (length--) {
        method = methods[length];

        // Only stub undefined methods.
        if (!console[method]) {
            console[method] = noop;
        }
    }
}());
```

Specifically I am interested in this line of code

```
var console = (window.console = window.console || {});
```

Why are we creating a new `window.console` object if `window.console` is not defined ?

So why are we setting `window.console={}`?

Answer (score 6):

This creates a dummy windows.console for older browsers to prevent them from throwing errors. First an empty function is created and then the missing function calls are added (without any real functionality).